# Adding datapoints to a boxplot

Tags: graphics, boxplot

R beginner here so sorry for the basic question...  I have worked in class to draw some boxplots using the boxplot() function. As part of the assignment I've been asked to add data points to the boxplots. I can't seem to find an argument in the boxplot() function to do this...Is there another function I need to use? Thank you!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend looking into ggplot2 package within R.
You can create multiple visualizations, including a boxplot with the data points shown. This is the ggplot code to do so:

```
library(ggplot2)
 ggplot(df, aes(x=catvar, y=yvar)) + 
  geom_boxplot()+geom_dotplot(binaxis='y', stackdir='center', dotsize=1)
```